# convert the string received from android into jsonArray and loop through it in php

Tags: php, parsing

I receive the following as a string in php using this command

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

the string i receive is not exactly in the json format. it contains introduceesJson=[], which is unique.

The String i receive is as follows:

```
introduceesJson=
[
{"oneWay":"1","destNumber":"98 65 326569","infoName":"Aa",
"infoNumber":"96 35"},
{"oneWay":"1","destNumber":"98 65 326569","infoName":"Bb",
"infoNumber":"82 77"},
{"appVersion":"1.0","packetType":"1","packetVersion":"1.0",
"deviceType":"android"}
]
```

Now, i want all the details to be stored in an array. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I tried this. It didnt work.  $jsonObj = json_decode($jsonString, true);   $jsonArray = $jsonObj['introduceesJson'];       foreach($jsonArray as $json)
 {
  foreach($json as $key=>$value)
        array_push($arr, $value); 
  //break;
 }

Comment: If your input includes `introduceesJson=` it is not valid json and you would need to remove that first. Or better, avoid getting invalid json in the first place if possible.

Comment: @amdixon, could you please post the code to do it?. Btw, thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @jeroen, I am putting json array inside json object in android. It is necessary to give a name.

Comment: I don't know how / what you are sending, but perhaps you just need something like `$_POST['introduceesJson']` instead.

Comment: @jeroen, yes. now i get the string without "introduceesJson=". Could you please tell me how to convert the rest into a json array or php array so that i could loop through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read/map a json string to a php object use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**example**

```
<?php

$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');

$json = str_replace("introduceesJson=", "", $jsonstring);

$ob1 = json_decode($json, true);

// add your application-specific code for processing $ob1 here..

var_dump($ob1);

?>
```

Then you can add your application-specific logic to process the php object

Answer (score 1):

```
$introduceesJson=
'[
{"oneWay":"1","destNumber":"98 65 326569","infoName":"Aa",
"infoNumber":"96 35"},
{"oneWay":"1","destNumber":"98 65 326569","infoName":"Bb",
"infoNumber":"82 77"},
{"appVersion":"1.0","packetType":"1","packetVersion":"1.0",
"deviceType":"android"}
            ]';
        $resultArray = json_decode($introduceesJson, true);
    foreach($resultArray as $key => $value)
    {
    foreach($value as $k=> $v)
    //your key and values are here 
    }
```